# How do I change all tables in my database to use AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Tags: mysql, database

I have about 30 tables in my database:

`table1` `table2` `table3` `table4` `table5` etc.

I want all tables to use `AUTO_INCREMENT=1`, how do I modify the tables?

Here is the sample DDL of one of the tables. I have never defined `AUTO_INCREMENT` in any of the tables, it is fetching the value by default.

```
CREATE TABLE `amenities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to be used for new rows, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

To update all your 31 tables you can use this php script:

```
<?php
$tables = array('table1','table2','tableX'); //continue here
foreach($tables as $update)
{
     mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `".$update."` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's what they invited copy/paste for. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
select concat('alter table ',table_name,' auto_increment = 1;') 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db';
```

then run the output generated.
By the way this is a strange questions. If you use `truncate table_name` your auto_increment value will restart from 1.

edit. You could use into outfile to redirect the queries within a txt file and then recall it.

```
select concat('alter ',table_name,' auto_increment = 1;') 
into outfile 'd:/queries.txt'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db'
```